# JavaFX css controls customizing

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I have css style class:

```
.customTabPane {
     -fx-tab-min-height: 20;
}
.customTabPane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 5 0 0 0;
}

.customTabPane:top *.tab {
    -fx-padding:  0 0 0 0;
}

.customTabPane *.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

But *.tab-header-area, *.tab-header-background apply for all TabPane-s in application, not only for "customTabPane" (`tabPane.getStyleClass().add("customTabPane")`). How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your use case, and the css is applied only to that tabpane which has a "customTabPane" style class. Check your code again.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.getStyleClass().add("customTabPane");
    tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("tab 1"));

    TabPane tabPane2 = new TabPane();
    tabPane2.getTabs().add(new Tab("tab 2"));

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(tabPane,tabPane2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```